# Impossible to insert null values Azure, Android SDK

Tags: c#, android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a c# backend with nullable type and with swift I am able to insert null values but with Android is not possible. I have also tried to pull data using postman and it works perfect but when I use the insert method of MobileServiceSyncTable and MobileServiceJsonSyncTable is not possible. I have tried to add values manually into the json object with value JSONObject.NULL but is also not possible.

```
 mClient = Client.getInstance();
 jsonTable= new MobileServiceJsonSyncTable("myTable", mClient);

 JsonObject item2 = new JsonObject(); 
 item2.addProperty("n_r1", 1); 
 item2.addProperty("n_r2", null); 
 item2.add("n_r3",JsonNull.INSTANCE); 
 jsonTable.insert(item2).get();

//push data to azure
MobileServiceSyncContext syncContext = mClient.getSyncContext();
syncContext.push().get();
jsonTable.pull(null).get();
```

I am not getting any error, it inserts the data but for example with 0 instead of null at doubles values. Here you can see that I am only sending three values n_r1 with value 1 and the n_r2,n_r3 with null

Plase take a look at the copy and paste of my rows in the database. The first row was inserted with the code and instead of null I get a 0. The second row is a test made with postman sending data as json like this `{"n_r1":null,"n_r2":null,"n_r4":1,"n_r5":1,"n_r6":1,"n_r7":7}` As you can see with postman nulls are insert perfectly.

```
n_r1    n_r2    n_r3    n_r4    n_r5    n_r6    n_r7    
1       0       0       0       0       0       0
NULL    NULL    NULL    1       1       1       7
```

Comment: Can you please show the code you are using and full error messages?

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I post it below because in comments is too short to answer